# Convert XML to CSV

Tags: python, csv, command-line-arguments, argparse

Here is my updated code and most of it works except one little thing at the generate_csv part. You can ignore all the generate_xml parts.

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
import csv
import indent
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def get_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Converts CSV to XML")
    parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose',action='store_true',dest='verbose',help='Increases messages being printed to stdout')
    parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="Please input the name of the CSV file")
    parser.add_argument('-o','--outputfile',help='(optional) Output file name',nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ext = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[1].lower()
    if args.outputfile is None:
        if ext == ".csv":
            args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.xml'

        elif ext == ".xml":
            args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.csv'

    elif args.outputfile:
        if ext == ".csv":
            outputfile = open(args.outputfile, 'w')
        elif ext == ".xml":
            outputfile = open(args.outputfile,'w')
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Invalid extension %s\n' % ext)
        sys.exit(1)
    return args

def main(argv):
    args = get_args(argv[0:])
    if args is None:
        return 1
    ext = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[1].lower()
    if ext == ".csv":
        reader = read_csv(open(args.inputfile))
        generate_xml(reader, args.outputfile)

    if ext == ".xml":
        root = etree.parse(open(args.inputfile)).getroot()
        generate_csv(root, args.outputfile)


    if args.verbose:
        print ('Verbose Selected')
    if args.verbose:
        print ('Convert to XML with set name')

    return 0 

def read_csv(inputfile):
    return list(csv.reader(inputfile))

def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)        
    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i > 0:
            x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
            if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

                collar = SubElement (current_group, 'collar',{'':', '.join((x1,y1,z1))}),
                toe = SubElement (current_group, 'toe',{'':', '.join((x2,y2,z2))})
                cost = SubElement(current_group, 'cost',{'':cost})
        i+=1
    head.set('total_holes', '%s'%i)
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)

def generate_csv(root, outfile):

    with open(outfile, 'w') as file_:

        writer = csv.writer(file_, delimiter="\t")

    for a in zip(root.findall("drillholes/hole/collar"),
                 root.findall("drillholes/hole/toe"),
                 root.findall("drillholes/hole/cost")):
        writer.writerow([x.text for x in a])

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Here is my new code but at writer.writerow([x.text for x in a]) there is an error that says: I/O operation on a closed file. How do i fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_name = sys.argv[1]
    csv_file_name = '.'.join(file_name.split('.')[:-1]) + ".csv"

    root = etree.parse(file_name).getroot()

    with open(csv_file_name, 'w') as file_:

        writer = csv.writer(file_, delimiter="\t")

        for a in zip(root.findall("drillholes/hole/collar"),
                     root.findall("drillholes/hole/toe"),
                     root.findall("drillholes/hole/cost")):
            writer.writerow([x.text for x in a])
```

Comment: thanks what if i want to give parameters in the command line, for exmaple: argparse.py test.xml, if i input that in the command line it will give me test.csv.

Comment: Then you can `import sys` and extract the name of the file(s) to parse through `sys.argv[1]`, `sys.argv[2]` and so on. Just replace the string literal in the `open(...)` call with the appropriate variable. http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: i recieve an error at writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t") and says type error: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Comment: @Andy did you change all the `file_` variables to `outfile` variables, I am almost certain the error you are experiencing is a "copy/paste" error.

Comment: i have to change the parameters only everything else is same